# Line class is obsolete, use Polynomial class instead

Tags: c#, polynomials

I'm working on a personal math project updating some code that uses an old version of `Extreme.Numerics.Curves.Line`.

The `Line` class takes four args: `x1, y1, x2, y2`.

When I try to use the newer `Polynomial` class, it doesn't take four args like the `Line`. It has the following method signatures:

```
    public Polynomial(int degree);
    public Polynomial(IList<double> coefficients);
    public Polynomial(double[] coefficients, bool descendingOrder);
    public Polynomial(IList<double> coefficients, bool descendingOrder);
```

Which of these can I use and how?

Comment: `Polynomial.GetInterpolatingPolynomial` perhaps, reading the docs? Or work out the coefficients yourself?

Comment: @canton7 - GetInterpolatingPolynomial looks like it could work, thanks

Comment: *hint* - A line is [y=mx+b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial), or a polynomial of degree 1.  Another one of those times where *"what are we ever going to use this stuff for?"* in grade 10 math comes back to bite one in the behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the `(x_1,y_1)` and `(x_2,y_2)` are the coordinates of two points the line joins.

The polynomial function needs coefficients in ascending order such that

`Polynomial( [c_0,c_1, c_2, ..] ) = c_0 + c_1*x + c_2*x^2  ..`

The following code uses the first two coefficients to define a line to convert between coordinate points and coefficients.

```
var coef = new[] { (x_1*y_2-x_2*y_1)/(x_1-x_2), (y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)};
var line = new Polynomial(coef, false);
```

Note that the equation of the line that joins two points is

[image: eq1]